# How to generate dynamically cell/columns with DataGrid?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

```cs
public class PrcDeployModel : BindableBase
{
    public ProcessComputerResult ProcessComputer { get; set; }

    public List<EnvironmentModel> Environments { get; set; }
}

public class EnvironmentModel
{
    public string Environment { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string User { get; set; }

    public DeployModel LatestDeployment { get; set; }
}
```

Above you see a class of Computers that have different environments. I now want to generate columns based on a list of these Computers in my `DataGrid`. I can successfully create my column headers with this code in the code behind. I want to generate a table with 1 column for the computer name, and then different columns based on the different environments.

```cs
public void FillTableColumns(List<PrcDeployModel> deployModels)
{
    DataGridDeployments.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn() { Header = "PRC" });

    foreach (var model in deployModels)
    {
        foreach (var environment in model.Environments)
        {
            var existingColumn = DataGridDeployments.Columns.FirstOrDefault(x =>
                environment.Environment != null && (string)x.Header == environment.Environment);
            if (existingColumn == null)
            {
                DataGridDeployments.Columns.Add(new DataGridTemplateColumn() { Header = environment.Environment, IsReadOnly = true, Width = DataGridLength.Auto });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also know that I can generate the cells from the code behind and style them but I think this is overkill. I want in some way to work with binding and fill this `DataTemplate` for the environment columns:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="TestDataTemplate">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=IconSrc}" Width="60" Height="60" Margin="0 0 5 0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Environment}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date}" FontSize="14"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=User}" FontSize="14"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Or what is the best way to solve this problem of dynamic columns?

This is my table: the number of environment depends on the number of different environments in the list of `PrcDeployModels`:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can share a screenshot of a excel table or similar to visualize your expected result? It's quite hard to tell what is the best approach if we don't understand the problem...

Comment: @Mat I added a simple screenshot of the table in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

For the "binding part" instead of code behind you could use a nested `ItemsControl` instead of a `DataGrid`. Here you go with a inital solution to get an idea.

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProcessComputer}"/>
                    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Environments}" >
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Environment}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Date}" FontSize="14"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=User}" FontSize="14"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

code behind to create the sample data:

```
        List<PrcDeployModel> data = new List<PrcDeployModel>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            PrcDeployModel computer = new PrcDeployModel();

            computer.ProcessComputer = i.ToString();
            computer.Environments = new List<EnvironmentModel>();
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                EnvironmentModel env = new EnvironmentModel();
                env.Environment = $"env{j}";
                env.Date = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                env.User = "my user";
                computer.Environments.Add(env);
            }
            data.Add(computer);
        }

        this.DataContext = data;
```

However, your data seems quite unstructured. Not all Environments must exist on every machine and the number is unlimited. If it's really that complex I would rather introduce a class Environment and bind the columns based on that... maybe rethink your data model?